# Get the published date of a node

Tags: 8

I would like to get the published date of my node. On the site I created a news block with a view. In the view I added a field and customised it by the rewrite results with "published on `{{ created }}`". But sometimes I create the news the day before, then it shows the created date, but I will like to have the published date.

What's the name for the published date? `{{ publish_on }}` didn't works.

Comment: Out of the box a node only has two values, created or changed. If you add a field for published date, you would render that in twig as `{{ content.field_FIELDNAME }}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a **published date** out of the box.

You can try using [Publication Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/publication_date) module.

> The Publication Date module adds a "Published on" date for each node,
>   containing the date when it was first published.